# Reading all fields at once into a class object from FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

Project on Angularjs.
There is an input form with a set of fields. The documentation provides examples of how to read each field separately. And you can read all the fields at once and save it in the class (or probably better in the Fruit interface).
And most importantly, will it work correctly if the number of fields in the Fruit interface does not match their number in the fruitForm form?

```
fruit!: Fruit;

fruitForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(),
  ... there are 5 more fields
  series: new FormControl('series-01')
});
onFormSubmit(): void {
  console.log('Name:' + this.fruitForm.get('name').value);
  ...
  console.log('Series:' + this.fruitForm.get('series').value);
}
```

interface / class

```
export interface Fruit {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ... there are 5 more fields
  series: string;
  data: Data;
}
```

Comment: What do you ultimately want to do with the form data? Are you doing something with it locally?

Comment: `this.fruitForm.getRawValue()`

Comment: I have 12 fields and I want to read them all at once, an object of type Fruit, and not read one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If you to display all of them in a single go.
Use `this.fruitForm.getRawValue()`;

or if you to iterate over them and and console.log their values like you did in your code

```js
Object.keys(this.fruitForm.controls).forEach(key => {
   console.log(key + ': ' + this.fruitForm.controls[key].value);
});
```